Base of absorbing and absolutely convex neighborhood of the origin for Locally Convex Topological Vector Spaces
Hello i'm trying to show the following result for Topological vector spaces and i'm stuck with the second part of the result:
$\textbf{Theorem}$
Given $\textbf{X}$ a locally convex topological vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, then it admits a base $\textbf{B}$ of absorbing and absolutely convex neighborhood of the origin such that the two following properties hold:
$$1)\forall U,V\in \textbf{B}\;\exists W \in \textbf{B} : W\subseteq U\cap V$$
$$2)\forall U \in \textbf{B}, \forall \lambda >0,\lambda \in \mathbb{R}\implies\lambda U \in \textbf{B}  $$
Conversely, given $\textbf{X}$ vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, if $\textbf{B}$ is a collection of absorbing and absolutely convex substes of $\textbf{X}$ such that properties $1)$ and $2)$ hold, then there exists a unic topology $\textbf{T}$ compatible with the structure of vector space of $\textbf{X}$ and such that $\textbf{B}$ is a base of neighborhood of the origin for this topology.
I proved the first part of the result but i'm stuck with the second part, the one that starts with $"Conversely..."$.
This is what I wrote for the second part:
$\textbf{Proof}$
Since $\forall B \in \textbf{B},\; B\;$is absorbent, then I have that
$0\in B$.
So I need to proved that this collection form a base for a topology. There is a lemma that says:
Given a set $\textbf{E}$ a collection $\textbf{C}$ of subsets of $\textbf{E}$ is a base for a topology if and only if two properties hold:
$$a)\forall U,V \in \textbf{C}\;\exists W \in \textbf{C} : W\subseteq U\cap V$$
$$b)\textbf{C}\;covers\;\textbf{E}$$
So applying this lemma to the collection $\textbf{B}$ i have that $a)$ is immediately satisfied by 1). To show that $b)$ holds true, I use the fact the every $B$ is absorbent and property $2)$.
So given $x\in\textbf{X}$ i have:
$$\forall U\in \textbf{B}\;\exists r>0\; s.t.\;x\in rU$$
Then, using property $2)$ i have that $rU\in\textbf{B}$ and so also $b)$ holds true.
Then this shows that $\textbf{B}$ is a base for a topology $\textbf{T}$ on $\textbf{X}$.
From here it is also possible to show that $\textbf{B}$ is a base of neighborhoods of $0$. Indeed, if I take $N$ as a neighborhood of $0$, then since $\textbf{B}$ is a base for $\textbf{T}$, there exists $A\in\textbf{T}$ such that $0\in A\subseteq N$. But $\textbf{B}$ is a base for $T$, so there exists $B\in \textbf{B}$ such that $0\in B\subseteq A\subseteq N$. And this shows that $\textbf{B}$ is a base of neighborhoods of 0.
So now i need to show that this topology is compatible with the structure of vector space; but i don't know how to show for example that the function:
$+:\textbf{X}\times\textbf{X}\rightarrow\textbf{X}$ is continuous.
I'm sure that i have to use somehow the fact that $\textbf{B}$ is a base of absorbing and absolutely convex neighborhoods of 0, but i can't figure out what to do.
Can someone explain me how to do or give me just a hint please?
P.S.
I'm trying to avoid using seminorms because our professor gave us this result, leaving the proof as an exercise, in a chapter before introducing seminorms.

A set $A$ is open in the topology you are looking for if, for any $a\in A$, there is $U\in B$ with $a+U\subseteq A$. If you have seen Minkowski functionals $p_U(x)=\inf{t>0: x\in tU}$ (which are realvalued seminorms), the translates $a+U$ correspond to balls ${x\in X: p_U(a-x)<1}$ (more precisely, this open ball is cantained in $a+U$ which is contained in the closed ball). Radius $1$ is enough because the scaled sets $\lambda U$ also belong to $B$.
